# Where is web streaming music saved on my PC?

Tags: streaming, website, disk-space, music

Where is web streaming music saved on my PC?

Comment: Wherever your streaming program puts it. So what streaming program are you using, and how did you configure it? (And if you didn't configure anything, it's probably not saving the data: that's what streaming is all about.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This totally depends on the software you use for streaming; it can save the music wherever it likes or not.

Most likely, however, the music is not saved at all. It is only buffered (in RAM), then discarded after playback.

Many proprietary music players do not offer saving streams on purpose, to protect streams from being copied.

Answer (score 1):

If its streamed to you, it may not be saved on your Computer. There are a number of programs which will allow you to save the stream.